# phpbrew 5.3.10 build error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

Tags: php, c++, ubuntu

I am trying to compile an old version of php for testing using phpbrew but I am encountering the following build error:

```
/home/ubuntu/.phpbrew/build/php-5.3.10/ext/dom/node.c:1900:40: error: 
dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
 RETVAL_STRINGL((char *) buf->buffer->content, ret, 1);
```

I have included all the libraries that phpbrew has indicated should be included, however I don't understand how to fix this build error or what it even means.

Comment: looks like phpbrew already has something in the [issue tracker (#249)](https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew/issues?q=dereferencing+pointer+to+incomplete+type) and under [TroubleShooting](https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew).

Answer (score 9):

I had the similar problem and it was because of my installed `libxml2` version was newer than 2.9.0. So as explained [here](https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew/wiki/TroubleShooting#error-dereferencing-pointer-to-incomplete-type) you can fix it by applying the following patch:
Go to your php source folder:

```
$ cd ~/.phpbrew/build/php-{version}/
```

Then download and apply the following patch:

```
$ curl -s https://mail.gnome.org/archives/xml/2012-August/txtbgxGXAvz4N.txt | patch -p0
```

Now try to compile and everything should be fine.

Comment: That works  `phpbrew install --old 5.3.7 +default+etc ` on debian 9  with a old openssl and old curl compiled on the same system